# phing parameters

Tags: deployment, centos, phing

for deployment, we use the awesome tool PHING.
We'd like to be able to pass a parameter to the "phing" command when deploying, like this:

```
phing 1.1.1
```

-> we would like to capture 1.1.1 inside the phing build script to extract a certain SVN TAG from our repository and move that tag to production.

Is that something that's possible?

Comment: http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#PropertyPromptTask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

phing has a PromptTask that ask for information like this.

solved!

Comment: http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#PropertyPromptTask

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
phing -Dversion=1.1.1 -Dparam=value
```

see https://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/175